# Python logging typeerror

Tags: python, debugging, logging, typeerror, info

Could you please help me, whats wrong.

```
import logging

if (__name__ == "__main__"):
    logging.basicConfig(format='[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s::%(module)s::%(funcName)s() %(message)s', level=logging.DEBUG)
    logging.INFO("test")
```

And I can't run it, I've got an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/htfuws/Programming/Python/just-kidding/main.py", line 5, in 
    logging.INFO("test")
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Is this the whole code?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

[`logging.INFO` denotes](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#logging-advanced-tutorial) an integer constant with value of 20

> INFO  Confirmation that things are working as expected.

What you need is [`logging.info`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.info)

```
logging.info("test")
```

Comment: thank you very much, I was using it in my previuos project and I was wondering why it doesn't work. AND I DID NOT NOTICE the LOWER CASE. Ah.

Comment: my god man, this has been the source of so much frustration for me.

Answer (score 11):

You are trying to call `logging.INFO`, which is an integer constant denoting one of the pre-defined logging levels:

```
>>> import logging
>>> logging.INFO
20
>>> type(logging.INFO)
<type 'int'>
```

You probably wanted to use the [`logging.info()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.info) (note, all *lowercase*) instead:

> Logs a message with level `INFO` on this logger. The arguments are interpreted as for `debug()`.

Comment: thank you very much, I was using it in my previuos project and I was wondering why it doesn't work. AND I DID NOT NOTICE the LOWER CASE. Ah.

Comment: And you did not notice the CAPS LOCK either, by the looks of it. :-P (And sorry, you can only mark *one* answer as accepted, thanks for the brief acceptance though!)