# AttributeError: 'Logger' object has no attribute ‚WARNING'

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I tried to implement a logger into my python script according to the [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html). This is the code:

```
import logging

def generateLogger(loggername='SM-Logger', path="logs/log.log"):

    logger = logging.getLogger(loggername)
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    ch = logging.StreamHandler()
    ch.setLevel(logging.ERROR)

    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s\
                              - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

    ch.setFormatter(formatter)

    logger.addHandler(ch)

    return logger

logger = generateLogger("testlogger", "testlog.log")
logger.WARNING("testtest")
```

I get this error message:

```
File "loggertest.py", line 39, in <module>
    logger.WARNING("testtest")
AttributeError: 'Logger' object has no attribute ‚WARNING'
```

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18292500/python-logging-typeerror?rq=1

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The solution is to change the last line

```
logger.WARNING("testtest")
```

into

```
logger.warning("testtest")
```

Lower-case "warning" is the function, upper-case "WARNING" is the variable.